# symfony или slim framework

Tags: php, symfony, slim

На php разрабатываю более 7 лет. 
Готовые фреймворки никогда не использовал, за исключением отдельных компонентов (или библиотек monolog, guzzlehttp и т.д.).

Хочется наконец начать осваивать какой-то фреймворк, чтобы из коробки меть правильную архитектуру, роутеры и т.д.

Мне больше приятен symfony, но из-за его громоздкости (миллион классов сразу из коробки), я не рисковал углублятся в этом.

Хочется постепенно начать, и расширять. Т.е. Роутеры, контроллеры, middleware и т.д. (с mvc тоже не знаком, вот так вот за 7 лет..) А дальше уже всякие доктрины и т.д.

Сейчас встал перед выбором, стоит ли начинать с symfony (читал, что в новой версии все урезали по умолчанию, и оставили минимум) или все же с микрофреймворка slim начать ?

Comment: А прошлый вопрос что - закрыли? Закрыли тот - закроют и этот.

Comment: Если сразу сложно изучать symfony изучайте что проще. Могу порекомендовать codeignitor как более понятный. Ищите что вам по силам и интересно.

Comment: Для symfony есть официальные курсы. Может стоит всё же присмотреться к ним? И ничего там не урезали. Просто убрали часть всего того, что идёт из коробки. Но это можно всё подключить по необходимости, как обычный пакет. К томе же самая база есть в skeleton шаблоне - самый-самый минимум всего.

Comment: О какой громоздкости вы говорите ? Нынче симфони минимален. Естественно начинайте с него.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше начинать с Symfony. Во-первых, сообщество намного шире (быстрее можно найти/получить ответ, если упираешься в какую-то проблему). Во-вторых, он уже задает какую-никакую архитектуру проекта, чего я не могу сказать о Slim.